# What is the standard way of an active client passing a SAML token to a relying party?

Tags: asp.net, ios, wcf, wif

I have a mobile client (iOS) and a web service (WCF, .NET 4.5) that I am securing using Windows Identity Foundation and SAML tokens. I have my client requesting SAML tokens from a custom STS, and once my relying party has that token I am able to deserialize it and verity its claims.

However, I am uncertain if there is a standard way to send the token from the client to the relying party? I am guessing the token should be in the header of each request, but is there a common header or cookie name that is used when passing this type of token?

I could see how you would want it to be different in all cases, in case multiple tokens were being passed back and forth, but I am wondering what the standard is for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

If the RP is WCF, then yes.. the bindings all take care of that. If the RP is something else (such as a HTTP/REST service) then it's up to you and your protocol to send it. So yea, you can just send it as a HTTP header. The RP would then need to know to look for the token and validate it. This doesn't exist today in WebAPI, so you can use the Thinktecture IdentityModel security library to accept and validate tokens in HTTP headers:

http://thinktecture.github.io/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.45/

Comment: I agree that WCF bindings should take care of that, but I am wondering how to submit the token on a non-.NET client in a way that the bindings will be able to work properly. That is interesting about the WebAPI not having any support for this yet - I will have to take a look at your link for future work I will be doing.

Answer (score 0):

The more logical thing to do is to pass a JWT token (there is an official Microsoft implementation available on nuget).  These are much smaller and are easier to handle on non .NET clients (such as JavaScript ...).  Since they are smaller, you can pass them in an http header; typically "Authorization space Bearer space encoded JWT token".  In you wep api you then need an httpfilter to interpret this data and authorize or reject the call.
Of course, you can do the same with a SAML token.  You will needed to encoded it somehow and it will add considerably to the size of your communication.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's the more logical thing to do... JWT is just the serialization format, and the client should not care about that. The client is just retrieving and sending the token to the RP. The client should not be reading it - in fact in some cases it can't because the token will be encrypted. I agree that the size would differ, but my token is fairly small at the moment.

Comment: JWT is indeed just a serialization format.  In my case it ends up 3 times smaller and readable by the JavaScript mobile clients.  My JWT tokens aren't encrypted (only signed) and the client doesn't verify the signature (the web api does).  Regardless of that, the client is still capable of handling expiration etc ...